# Golang Testing > cant load package

Tags: go, bdd

I am having an issue with the built in testing for go lang.

I keep getting this error.

```
> go test
> can't load package: package .: found packages main (calculator.go) and calculator (calculator_test.go) in
```

calculator.go

```
package main

func main() {

}
```

calculator_test.go

```
package calculator

import "testing"

func TestAdd(t *testing.T) {
    result := Add(1, 3)
    if result != 4 {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

Comment: And I had the package's listed wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have

```
package main

func main() {}
```

in file `calculator.go`.

and

```
package calculator
```

in file `calculator_test.go`.

They should both be

```
package main
```